# What is the antonym of "interdisciplinary"?

Tags: word-request

What is the antonym of "interdisciplinary"? 
I want to say that articles related to particular related major or specializations are accepted as well as inter-disciplinary articles.

Answer (score 1):

Intra-disciplinary may work. (Generally, intra- and inter- are used as antonymous prefixes.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an actual antonym to "interdisciplinary",
but it comes from "discipline" which designates **a single** discipline (when the singular is used), so you can use that.

I guess you could say

> articles related to **a particular discipline** are accepted as well as inter-disciplinary articles.'

You could use "any discipline" as well but it's less precise and might not be suited if you want to specify that it is "a particular" discipline.

Comment: Does uni-disciplinary make sense?

Comment: I would tend to say yes. I could not find it in a dictionary so i don't think it is an actual word, but it seems to be used sometimes and people should understand it.