# Is "unidisciplinary" a valid word?

Tags: word-request

Is unidisciplinary a valid English word? I want to use it as an [antonym of interdisciplinary](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62388/what-is-the-antonym-of-interdisciplinary).

Comment: If one were to coin a word meaning the opposite of "interdisciplinary," "intradisciplinary" would probably be the most direct choice. It's not in the dictionary, but it would be readily understood, as those prefixes are frequently taken in contrast to one another.

Answer (score 2):

While "unidisciplinary" may not appear in any general dictionary, its use is well-attested, as a simple Google search will show. In addition, a unidisciplinary healthcare team is defined, according to [Mosby's Medical Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/unidisciplinary+health+care+team). The word also can be spotted in *Hospice: Practice, Pitfalls, and Promise* (1998).

"Unidisciplinary" is attested as far back as 1978, in 
*Strategy Formulation as a Learning Process: An Applied Managerial Theory of Strategic Behavior*. This gives it a longer pedigree than "google." "Monodisciplinary" can also be spotted.

Comment: I'm reading I. Wallersteins "Modern World-System I" from 1974 and it's used there, too, on page 11 of the introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Your meaning would be understood but I think you'd be inventing a word.  Try:

> specialized
>
> narrowly-focused
>
> field-specific

"Esoteric" also comes to mind, but be careful with that one; it's a bit formal / wordy and more accurately means "understood by few" than "pertaining to a single discipline".

Answer (score 0):

Monodisciplinary is the word you need. Unidisciplinary means completely opposite. It means more than metadisciplinary, in short knowledge without disciplines. It is used by Emmanuil Wallerstein in his "World Systems Analysis" to refer to this meaning.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include some more details? Do you have some references to support you? How or when is it used?